# InfoPath & SharePoint not Communicating

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

Ok so I am not a TOTAL beginner in InfoPath yet I have this annoying issue with fields populating in SharePoint.

So I have a column created in a SharePoint Library called "Type" with three options: A, B, C (I have simplified for sake of explanation).

I have a form that publishes to this same library.
I have an additional (retrieve) data connection that is pulling that field into InfoPath to make it available. All this works so far.

However, when I create a rule for the form to populate this same SharePoint field with "A" when the user submits the form, nothing gets sent to that column in SharePoint - it stays blank.

What am i doing wrong?